# GitHub page failed to display html image file

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I have created an HTML image file and I wanted to render it in my GitHub page. The image is stored here: https://github.com/WCRF/SysRev-Metan/blob/main/trial_fig.html. I tried to embed this image in my markdown document using this code.

```
 <figure>
    <iframe src="https://github.com/WCRF/SysRev-Metan/blob/main/trial_fig.html" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></iframe>
</figure>
```

However, the image is not showing up on my page and it is showing "github.com refused to connect" [image]
The image actually was displayed once and after that, it didn't work well. I also tried to drop the image in google drive(public) and used the google drive link. But it still didn't show the image.

I also tried the {% include_relative figpath/fig.html" %} but had no success.
If I do that from the readme file, it correctly renders it.

Answer (score 0):

Github HTTP header have :  `X-Frame-Options: deny`  and you can't load github pages inside `iframe`